Title: Steering Instability on Apache RR310 (BMW G310RR) During Left Turns
Lately, I’ve noticed a sudden and unnaturally quick dip in the steering when making left turns on my Apache RR310 (BMW G310RR). It feels like the handlebars are locking to the left, causing the bike to lean excessively fast in that direction. Tire pressure is optimal, but there is a minor bend in the front disc following a low-speed frontal collision (<40 KMPH). This issue has made me uncomfortable taking fast left-hand corners, and I’m seeking advice on how to address it.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like you need to have your forks trued. I'm  not a motorcycle guy, but know if the front end was in a collision, it could get the triple tree out of alignment or one/both of the forks bent, causing the issue you're talking about. I don't think I'd be riding it, either.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you. Is there a way I can fix it? The service centers are literally useless to the point that they think it is manageable and isn't much of an issue, but I can feel the difference in my bike's handling. Also the bike is currently my only mode of transport

I don't have an answer for you, but wish I did. I don't know the first thing about repairing the front end of a bike, other than what I watched on American Choppers. I'd say to poke around your area and see if there are any enthusiasts who can either help you or point you in the right direction.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you, Ill look into that
